# Regex to modify specific URLs in large strings

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having trouble getting my regex to work (big surprise)

I'm trying to replace urls in a large body of text:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/any/number/of/directories/picture.jpg" ...

<img src="http://www.example.com/any/number/of/directories/picture.gif" ...
```

With:

```
<img src="/LocalDirectory/images/picture.jpg" ...
```

I want to maintain the name of the images, and I can't have any false postives as the original text will contain other URLs I want to leave alone.  I only want to modify the pictures so can match on either jpg|jpeg|gif|png etc or the

I am doing this in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I already have this handy, this should grab the URL itself:

```
(?<=src=")[^"]+(?=")
```

Verified in [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/), this regular expression uses a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead to grab the url inside of src="".

I'll see if I can come up with something more specific to your task...

OK, this should work:

```
(?<=src=")[^"]+(/[^/]+(\.jpg|\.gif))(?=")
```

And then you can use a replacement value of:

```
/LocalDirectory/images$1
```

Or here's the complete C# code:

```
string strRegex = "(?<=src=\")[^\"]+(/[^/]+(\.jpg|\.gif))(?=\")";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.None;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = "<img src=\"http://www.example.com/any/number/of/directories/picture.jpg\" />" & vbCrLf & "<img src=\"http://www.example.com/any/number/of/directories/picture.gif\" />";
string strReplace = "/LocalDirectory/images$1";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

Comment: Note that ' is valid for wrapping attribute values (instead of ") in HTML 4.01, so this won't work for all pages.

Answer (score 1):

URL-matching with regular expressions is extremely difficult, if not impossible. Unless you have some extra constraints on what your URLs in your documents contain, in which case you can sacrifice flexibility of your regex in exchange for practicality.

Comment: As all I want is the last bit of the url (i.e. the filename). The filename can only be jpg etc, there will be an img src="http:// at the beginning.

Comment: It's a little easier when the URL is contained within an href of an HTML file.  Then you can know where the URL starts and stops.

Comment: Then you should use some HTML scraping library to get at the image tags' src attributes, before using a regex on the URIs. Try to avoid using regexs to parse HTML itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
strTargetString = "img tags to check";
string strRegex = "src=\"(.*)/(.*)\.(jpg|png|gif)\"";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);

string strReplace = "src="\/LocalDirectory\/images\/$2\.$3"";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

Misread the question.  This will now replace the first part of the path for jpg, png and gif and keep the filename.  anything else is ignored

Comment: No worries. His looks neater than mine

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
var replace = "/localserver/some/directory/";
var strs = new List<string>
{
    "<img src=\"http://www.example.com/any/number/of/directories/picture.jpg\"",
    "<img src=\"http://www.example.com/any/number/of/directories/picture.gif\"" 
};

Regex r = new Regex("[^<img src=\"].*/");

foreach (var s in strs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Replaced: {0}",r.Replace(s,replace));
}
```

outputs:

```
Replaced: <img src="/localserver/some/directory/picture.jpg"
Replaced: <img src="/localserver/some/directory/picture.gif"
```